# Cannot find symbol (Dagger Hilt)

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am using Dagger Hilt in my project and I got this error message:

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projeler\kotlin-coroutines-master\LOTRApp-master\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\example\lotr\BaseApplication_ComponentTreeDeps.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
import hilt_aggregated_deps._com_example_lotr_presentation_BookListViewModel_HiltModules_BindsModule;
^
symbol:   class _com_example_lotr_presentation_BookListViewModel_HiltModules_BindsModule
location: package hilt_aggregated_deps

How can I fix it?

**BaseApplication:**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication : Application() {

}
```

**build.gradle(:app):**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lotr"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.10'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"
    def coroutines_version = "1.5.2"
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    def ktor_version = "1.6.3"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version")

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version")

    // Annotation processor
    kapt("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version")
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version")

    //Dagger Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07")
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03'

    //Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.2")

    //Ktor
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.0"

}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

**build.gradle(project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.6.0-M1")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**BookListViewModel:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class BookListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val bookRepository: BookRepository
) : ViewModel(){

    val state = mutableStateOf(BookListState())

    init {
        getBooks()
    }

    private fun getBooks() {
        bookRepository.getBooks().onEach { result ->
            when(result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    state.value = BookListState(books = result.data ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    state.value = BookListState(error = result.message ?: "Unexpected Error")
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    state.value = BookListState(isLoading = true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

}
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project and then rebuild it.